# Changed spell check language; Word and Pages still use the old language

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, spell-check, iwork-pages

I moved from the U.S. to Canada, and I'm changing my Mac to spell check in Canadian English instead of American. I went to System Preferences > Language & Text > Text > Spelling, and changed the setting to "Canadian English." Most applications (such as Mail & TextEdit) now use Canadian spellings. But Word and Pages still use American English -- they tell me that colour, favourite, neighbourhood, etc. are misspelled. How do I get Word and Pages to default to Canadian English?

With Word, I can change the document's language with Tools > Language. But I have to do that for every document.

I've logged out of my account and rebooted. That doesn't help.

The versions I'm running are:

- Word for Mac 2011 (14.1.4)
- Pages '09, version 4.1 (923)
- MacOS X version 10.6.8

**Update**: Based on Daniel Beck's answer for Pages, I was able to figure out how to change the language in Word. I had to edit Normal.dotm and change the language there. Here are the steps:

1. Open Word
2. Using File > Open, open ~/Library/Application Support/Microsoft/Office/User Templates/Normal.dotm. (Double-clicking in the Finder doesn't work; you have to use File > Open.)
3. Command-A to select all text
4. Use Tools > Language to change the language to Canadian English.
5. Save Normal.dotm

Now new Word documents use Canadian English.

Comment: Does it only happen with existing documents, or also with newly created documents?

Comment: It happens with newly-created documents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pages uses the system languages to determine the default spell-checking language in new documents. You need to set this to *Canadian English*, then new documents will use *Canadian English* as spell-checking language by default.

[image]

<sup>(Screenshot is OS X Lion)</sup>

---

Alternatively, if you require more flexibility and only use a small number of templates by default (e.g. the *Blank* templates), you can create new documents based on them and set their spell-checking language in the document inspector (after selecting all text).

[image]

Then select *File » Save as Template…* and name it e.g. *Canadian English Blank*. From then on, the template will be available from the template chooser. Pages will remember the template category selected when you created a new document previously, so you don't even need to click *My Templates* all the time.

[image]

Comment: @Evan You're welcome. I don't have Word, so I can't help you with that, unfortunately. Consider splitting the question in two so others can answer the other part.